# LibSVM - interpreting model output

Tags: svm, matlab, libsvm

I am using libSVM on a subset of the MNIST, and I am struggling to interpret the output. I have learned that rho is the bias term, and that sv_coef is the multiplier used to get to the weight term. What is confusing me is the dimensions of the outputs:

```
    Parameters: [5×1 double]
      nr_class: 10
       totalSV: 4282
           rho: [45×1 double]
         Label: [10×1 double]
    sv_indices: []
         ProbA: [45×1 double]
         ProbB: [45×1 double]
           nSV: [10×1 double]
       sv_coef: [4282×9 double]
           SVs: [4282×784 double]
```

Why do we end up with dimensions of `45` for `rho` and `9` for the second dimension of `sv_coef`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in [here](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#f419), `libsvm` uses 1 vs 1 classifiers for multi-class classification (it's [not](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/multiclass-svms-1.html) the only option). So, it uses $n(n-1)/2$ binary SVM classifiers internally. Here, that makes $45$ classifiers, which explains the number of bias terms.

`sv_coef` [contains](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#f804) $n-1$ columns. Number of rows is equal to number of SVs. The number of SVs belonging to each class is stored in `nSV`. For example, let `nSV` be $[m_1\ m_2\ ...\ m_{10}]$. Then, first $m_1$ rows of `sv_coef` are $\alpha_iy_i$ coefficients belonging to $1$ vs $x$ classifiers, where $x$ change from $2$ to $10$, making it $9$ columns. The second $m_2$ rows belong to $2$ vs $x$ classifiers, where $x$ is all other classes but $2$ and so on.